# GLM Keeps Providing Choppy Transformation and Rotations

Tags: c++, opengl, math, transformation, glm-math

I'm currently experiencing a problem where GLM is providing choppy transformation and rotations. By this, I mean that they're not smooth. I'm using GLFW 3, GLM and OpenGL 3.2. I'm trying to transform a simple quad using joystick input. At first, I thought the problem was caused by the joystick. To disprove this, I change the code to rotate the quad independently from user-input, but dependent on deltaTime. Here are some code segments. I'm assuming it's with how I'm rotating the matrix?

**CPP file:**

```
float speed = 3.0f;
float deadZone = 0.10f;
glm::vec2 direction(0.0f);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    currentTime = glfwGetTime();
    deltaTime = (currentTime - lastUpdate) * 1000.0f;

    //Update logic
    inputHandler->tick(deltaTime);

    float inputX, inputY;
    inputX = inputHandler->getGamepad(0)->getAxes(AXIS::HORIZONTAL);
    inputY = inputHandler->getGamepad(0)->getAxes(AXIS::VERTICAL);

    float magnitude = sqrtf((inputX * inputX) + (inputY * inputY));
    if (magnitude > deadZone) //Radial dead zone detection
    {
        //Could the stutter be caused by type casting?
        direction.x += inputX * float((speed * deltaTime) / 1000.0f);
        direction.y += inputY * float((speed * deltaTime) / 1000.0f);
    }

    ... //Set vertex values and UV coord

    //Set the matrix values according to the joystick input
    glm::mat4 MVP(1.0f);
    MVP = glm::translate(MVP, glm::vec3(direction, 0.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    ...
}
```

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 150

in vec2 vertexPosition_modelspace;
in vec2 UV;

uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec2 vUV;

void main() {
    vUV = UV;
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: What does "choppy" mean? Do you just have a slow frame rate? GLM is not the problem.

Comment: No, it's not a framerate issue. I checked, and I'm constantly above 350FPS. I thought that maybe my framerate was too high, so I enabled VSync. Sadly, that didn't help anything. 

Here's an example of what I mean by choppy:
The object will be moving at a smooth 4px per tick, then suddenly, on a single tick, the object will move by ~32px.

Again, I checked my framerate while this jump happens and it never dips below 350 (59 while VSync).

Comment: Have you tried printing out the deltas for each tick?

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher I just tried it with VSync enabled. The constant output tanks the responsiveness of the window, but it seems like the deltaTime ranges anywhere from 0.2 - 0.5. It's hard to notice anything out of the ordinary due to the immense amount of outputs.

Comment: Create a time threshold - if your delta is higher than that, pause. Now examine the prints.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher I tried with a threshold of 0.7 and it seems like everyonce in a while, deltaTime hits anywhere from 1.0 - 2.2. I don't understand why it goes so high if I'm only rendering a single textured quad. There has to be something wrong. It even reproduces the stutter on my friend's i7 3930k with a high end GTX card (7 series, I think)

Comment: Are you running linux? I'm experiencing exactly this with a 3930k and GTX690 on Ubuntu 13.10. No amount of interpolation is helping; glm's matrix creation functions just occasionally randomly spike to 23-30ms once every few dozen frames. Happens with both glm::translate() AND glm::rotate().

Something is really broken somewhere. I checked my matrix data inputs, no outliers before the spikes. Definitely glm.

Comment: This is happening to me in Windows. It has to be GLM. I had no problems before it. I have hardly any experience when coding outside of GCC, so I kind of blamed VC++ (it or my lack of knowledge). Maybe we should try to submit a bug ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extremely frustrating, but I restarted Windows and all of the problems vanished. Even the one where a call to std::cout caused Visual Studio to insert a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some debugging help so as not to stay buried in the comments:

- Record the time step of each frame
- When the timestep is over some given threshold that you determine is enough to cause a "jump", pause the program.
- If the bug is coming from big time steps, track which functions take what amount of time and see if any take an unusual amount of time.

  i. If you have a profiler, use it here.

  ii. If not, record the time before and after each function and calculate the duration. Sum up these timesteps at the end of each frame so you can still find that total delta time that would indicate a jump.
- If you trace back your bug to some library/system/other call that you have no control over, make sure you're passing those functions (and really all functions) good data.

  i. Are you getting away with using corrupt memory somewhere?

  ii. Does bug only apply only to rotations? What about translations / scales?

  iii. Does this bug happen if you just run your program with trying OpenGL things? It could be an error with, say, your windowing, where you're missing some update call or something trivial like that.

Comment: I noticed that, while running the program with Microsoft's injected debugger (VC++ 2010), Visual Studio will throw in a break point every single time I output to std::cout if the data type isn't a const char *. If I run the program stand-alone, through explorer, I don't have any problems and it outputs to the console correctly. Does this mean I have mismanaged memory somewhere? Which could potentially be causing the stutter/choppyness?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `glfwGetTime` uses `QueryPerformanceCounter`. This is not the correct API to use for timing, as it measures "CPU time" not "Wall time". It should be used to measure code performance, but not much else. You should write your own timer class using `timeGetTime()`, `timeBeginPeriod()` and `timeEndPeriod()` from the Windows Multimedia Timers API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It used to measure number of cpu "cycles" executed and as the CPU ran at a fixed rate, it was a measure of real elapsed time. Then CPUs started running at variable rates so now it runs at some fixed rate as if the CPU ran at a constant speed. So it ought to work perfectly well for this.

There used to be issues on some broken multicore machines where it could read slightly different values on different cores and therefore go backwards, but that's not been an issue in practice for  along time now.

Comment: It was a long time ago that I ran into this issue, so you might be correct that it is no longer an issue, but the page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx suggests that buggy BIOS/HALs may be to blame for inconsistent results, so it still doesn't seem like the safest option.